Assigned texture leaking out of the area after aplying subdivision modifier


How to prevent assigned texture leaking from the area after applying subdivision modifier.

add an edge loop and slide it down close the angle?

so the only way is to add extra geometry?

You can use Ctrl E > Edge Crease, but apart from that I don't see.....

You can add an edge loop (CtrlR):

Or select the existing edge loop and CtrlE > Edge Crease, which will counter the Subdivision Surface effect:

